# Deflate algorithm in Java without Deflater class

Tags: java, compression, deflate

I want to compress a String with the Deflate algorithm in Java. But without the Deflater class because my task is to show how it is compressing. Does anybody have a pseudocode or any implementation? I do not know how to show the process with/without the deflater. How should I? The DEFAULT_COMPRESSION level is enough. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: instead of asking for solution, you should post what you have tried to implement and where you are stuck

Comment: What does "my task is to show how it is compressing" mean? Show what?

Comment: I'm stuck at the start, and I chose the task that i show how compressing algorithms work like Huffman. For example in Huffman you make a tree, in LZW you make a dictionary and you can read the compressed data from these.